# cannot find id in c programming lanuage

Tags: c, windows, block, codeblocks

In Code::Blocks when i run and debug my code it says in the "Build messages section" (error: Cannot find id) I reinstalled both the coding platform (code::blocks) and the compiler individually and nothing has changed.

Comment: Copy & paste the error text verbatim (in fact the entire build log) _all_ the available diagnostic information is important ; and it has to be accurate.  My bet is that it is `ld` not `id` - `ld` is the GNU linker.  If the code does not _build_ you are cannot "run and debug"  the menu name in Code::Blocks is wonderfully optimistic - should be "build, run & debug".

Comment: @Clifford _My bet is that it is `ld` not `id`  - ld is the GNU linker._  Mine too. I double the bet! +1 added.

Comment: error: ca not find 'ld'

Comment: ||=== Build: Debug in NO (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||error: cannot find 'ld'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simple program first to see if installation is correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```